# jQuery .append() function

Tags: jquery

Why [this](http://jsfiddle.net/muP6z/)

```
$("#mydiv").append("<ul>");
$("#mydiv").append("<li>Hello</li>");
$("#mydiv").append("</ul>");
alert($("#mydiv").html());
```

produces

`<ul></ul><li>Hello</li>`

and not

`<ul><li>Hello</li></ul>`

?

Thanks!

Comment: You should add the code here. So that other people can have a chance to see the whole question even when the external resource is gone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the browser needs to (re)build its DOM after each append. It can't know that a closing tag will come later, and an opening tag by itself is invalid, so error correction kicks in which in this case closes the unclosed element.

This is one of the reasons why `innerHtml` and things that rely on it (such as jQuery's append method) are not reliable and should be avoided when possible.

Comment: To be clear, append only relies on innerHtml if you pass it HTML string fragments. append itself appends a DOM node; if you pass in a string of HTML, it uses innerHTML to create a DOM node to then append as such.

Answer (score 7):

Append() appends DOM nodes, not HTML tags (i.e., it's an object append, not a string append).

When you append `<ul>`, you are creating an entire UL node, with both start and end tags. The `</ul>` call is ignored.

Comment: Better say *HTML tags* instead of *HTML elements*.

Comment: Strictly not every HTML element is a tag. You can append a TextNode that is not :-)

Answer (score 2):

Because you can't append the unfinished pieces of HTML, you always append the element. For your case you have do either

```
$("#mydiv").append("<ul></ul>");
$("#mydiv ul").append("<li>Hello</li>");
```

or

```
$("#mydiv").append("<ul><li>Hello</li></ul>");
```