# jquery $.each seems to be functioning asynchronously?

Tags: jquery

I'm writing an opening `div` tag, then using `$.each` to iterate through some JSON objects and write them into the `div`. After the `$.each` function, I'm writing the closing `div` tag. However, the closing `div` tag is getting written before the stuff within the `$.each` function executes and I can't figure out why. Here's my code:

```
$("#articles").append("<div id='stories'>");

$.each(articles, function(i, val) {
    $("#articles").append("<div class='story'><h1><a href='"+val.url+"'>"+val.title+"</a></h1><div class='dateline'>"+date+"</div><div class='summary'>"+body+"</div></div>");
});

$("#articles").append("</div>");
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery .append() function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2820394/jquery-append-function)

Comment: It's not a problem with `each`, you have a wrong understanding of `append`.

Answer (score 5):

It's not asynchronous.

All that's happening is that jQuery and the browser are refusing to allow you to create an unclosed element.

Every DOM manipulation function must leave the DOM consistent, so in your first line you're *actually* writing a whole `<div/>`, and then the following stuff is also appended to `#articles` rather than *inside* the new `<div>`.

Try this instead:

```
var $stories = $('<div id="stories" />').appendTo('#articles');

$.each(articles, function(i, val) {
    $stories.append("<div class='story'><h1><a href='"+val.url+"'>"+val.title+"</a></h1><div class='dateline'>"+date+"</div><div class='summary'>"+body+"</div></div>");
});
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I didn't realize that jQueury automatically closes tags like that. Your solution works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Make jQuery objects:

```
var $articles = $("<div id='stories'></div>");

$.each(articles, function(i, val) {
    $articles.append("<div class='story'><h1><a href='"+val.url+"'>"+val.title+"</a></h1><div class='dateline'>"+date+"</div><div class='summary'>"+body+"</div></div>");
});

$("#articles").append($articles);
```

Your code is "fixed" by jQuery when run, so this line will actually produce a closed `<div></div>` tag pair:

```
$("#articles").append("<div id='stories'>");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code and that will work perfectly

```
var storiesDiv = $("<div/>").attr('id', 'stories');

$.each(articles, function(i, val) {
    $(storiesDiv ).append("<div class='story'><h1><a href='"+val.url+"'>"+val.title+"</a></h1><div class='dateline'>"+date+"</div><div class='summary'>"+body+"</div></div>");
});

$("#articles").append(stroiesDiv);
```