# What is different about these two methods of appending a DOM element using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am experiencing different results from the two following bits of code. I thought, though, that they should perform identically. Could anyone enlighten me on the differences and when I should use one over the other?

```
function ContentHeader(selector){
    "use strict";
    var contentHeader = $(selector);

    var headerTitle = $('<span/>', {
        'class': 'headerTitle'
    }).appendTo(contentHeader);

    //OPTION A: This is my preferred method, but, after calling appendTo, no DOM element is added to the DOM tree.
    var headerTitleInput = $('<input/>', {
        'class': 'headerInput',
        type: 'text'
    }).appendTo(headerTitle);

    //OPTION B: By contrast, this method is less robust / just a string, but the DOM element is added correctly to the DOM tree.
    headerTitle.append('<input type="text" class="headerInput" />');
}
```

I would prefer to use jQuery's DOM object constructor since it neatly encapsulates properties, but apparently I do not fully understand it.

EDIT: I am working on generating a jsFiddle for this question. Please check back.

Comment: It doesn't look like you are appending anything to the page's main DOM tree in that code. You are just appending the stuff to each other but they're still disconnected.

Comment: There's more code. I was just trying to show the relevant bits. I've updated the posted code to show that it is encapsulated in a function responsible for generating the DOM element.

Comment: Ah sorry. It should work fine then. http://jsfiddle.net/brMC6/. The main difference is that the latter one uses the browser's html parser whereas the former one uses DOM APIs to create elements directly.

Comment: What browser are you using?  The jQuery documentation explicitly calls out `$('<input/>', {type: 'text'})` as something which doesn't work in IE.

Comment: @ephemient that should and does work in IE. Where in documentation you see that claimed?

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2820394/jquery-append-function

Comment: @Esailija http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2 "Internet Explorer will not allow you to create an input or button element and change its type; you must specify the type using `'<input type="checkbox" />'` for example."

Comment: @ephemient This is being developed as a Google Chrome Extension targeting the latest released version. I have "use strict" enabled in my JavaScript.

Comment: @ephemient That's completely false. You cannot change the input's type *after* it has been established as having some type. But you can initially set it just fine. I just tested in IE7-9 (compatibility mode, but still). In fact, look at: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/attributes.js#L377. It checks if the element has a parentNode and only then triggers the error. The documentation is out of sync with the source code. If you have real old IEs, test this http://jsfiddle.net/brMC6/1/.

Comment: @AaronKurtzhals It helps from an educational perspective, but the appendTo documentation shows that the input element should be inserted before the closing tag of span -- at least when viewing examples using <p> and <div> http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I tracked down the answer. Unfortunately, it's nothing sexy or educational.

When I create my ContentHeader object I return some public methods. One of which is called 'SetTitle.' It looks like so:

```
setTitle: function(title){
  headerTitle.text(title);
}
```

This method is interacted with during an asynchronous code-execution block which reaches out to a server. It seems that the overhead of creating a jQuery object was generating different, awkward results based on timing. The issue was not reproduceable inside of a jsFiddle.